# MYSQL how to combine duplicate rows numbers into one row with all data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How do I combine duplicate rows from the same table into one row total affiche  For example, if I have the following two rows:

```
| doc | grp | used
 h1     TC3  1.235
 h1     TC3  3.501
 h3     MR1  35
 h4     BB1  135
 h4     BB1  1.20
```

I want this affiche total in one row widout duplicate

```
| doc | grp | used
 h1     TC3  4.736
 h3     MR1  35
 h4     BB1  136.20
```

Comment: You are looking for `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions.

Comment: You need GROUP BY and SUM(). Something like: Select doc, grp, SUM(used) used from [YourTable] group by doc, grp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select doc,
       grp,
       sum(used) as used 
from table 
group by 1,2 order by 1
```